# 100% width only takes up half of mobile or laptop screen screen

Tags: html, css

Actually it has to be a little less that 100% because 100% sets it a little off screen to the right. When I load my page on a tablet or laptop screen it zooms into the top left of the screen, if I zoom out I see that the divs only take up about half the page left to right. I've tried playing around with min-width with no luck.

```
.first {
                height: 75px;
                width: 99.55%;
                background-color: red;
                margin-top: 19px;
                border: 3px yellow solid;
                min-width: 1000px;

                margin: 0 auto;

 }

 h2 {
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
 }
 <div class="animated fadeInUpBig first o">
        <h2>Need to fix positioning on mobile</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="animated fadeInUpBig first t">
        <h2>More work will be done tomorrow evening</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="animated fadeInUpBig first tr">
        <h2>Make it look half good by weekend</h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try `width: 100vw;` it will make element width 100% of screen

Comment: is your css in a <style> tag or css file?

Comment: If you use `vw` just bare in mind that IE 11 only has partial support and IE8 doesnt support it

Comment: @kuchar It stays the same as 100%; , only reaches about half way across the screen.

Comment: @Enkode It's a style tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting each red block with yellow border to span a specific width (to be 90%, 300px, etc.), you can add **box-sizing: border-box** to the element which allows for the width to include both padding and border. However since both the .first (a div) and the h2 are both block levels elements, by default they will take up 100% width of their parent.

I consolidated the margin-top with the margin: 0 auto; which keeps the margin: from overriding the margin-top.

Also the shorthand for border should be width, style, and color, so I have altered it slightly.

Lastly, the body element has a default margin of 8px in most browsers, so in order to get your boxes to touch the outside of the browser window, you'll want to add that last body property or use a common CSS reset (such as http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

```
.first {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  min-width: 1000px;
  margin: 19px auto 0;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/phawley/pen/amLRYK